# Can I use one "Getentry" to do different searches ( if I input "title" ,"author", "id" returns row containing title or author etc) is that possible?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite, android-activity

**Is there anyway** I use **one** "getentry" to do the different types of searches ( if I put in "title", it searches for row containing title. If i put in "id", it searches for row containing id etc) is that possible?

My table (book) has 3 columns

- Id
- Author
- Title

ID column is of integer data type

Author, Title columns are of string data type

```
Book getentry(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_AppData, new String[] { K_ID,
            K_AUTHOR K_TITLE }, K_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, );
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Book entry = new Book(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));

    return entry;
}
```

Comment: Like I said, I'm new to SQL Lite how would that apply to the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return a book based on the string value, that is contained in column columnName.

```
Book getentry(String value,String columnName) {

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_AppData, new String[] { K_ID,
        K_AUTHOR K_TITLE }, columnName + "=?",
        new String[] { value }, null, null, null, );
if (cursor != null)
    cursor.moveToFirst();

Book entry = new Book(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
        cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));

return entry;
```

Basically what you have to change is the third parameter, and the fourth parameter of db.query method.  The third one let's you specify which columns you want to sort by. The fourth one is the array of parameters that get replaced by the ? sign in the third one.

The first parameter is the DB name and the second one are the returned columns.

Edit : Make sure column name is equal to K_AUTHOR K_TTITLE or K_ID

Comment: Is there anyway I use one "Getentry" to do the different types of searches ( if I put in "title", it searches for row containing title. If i put in "id", it searches for row containing id etc) is that possible?

Comment: You could pass  the method what you want it to look for . I will edit the example.